# What does the phrase "arranging the coloured triangles of floating three-dimensional geometric figures" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Please help me understand the meaning of the phrase "coloured triangles of floating three-dimensional geometric figures" in the following sentence (not available online):

*In the game, your task involves arranging the **coloured triangles of floating three-dimensional geometric figures** in order to match the completed design shown at the top of the screen.*

The sentence is from the description of the game TRIZ. You can watch the gameplay [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OtjY4dUaTyg&t=204s).

Does the phrase mean that triangles are made of geometric figures?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, it's the geometric figures which are made up of triangles!

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for pointing this out. This makes the sentence clearer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A triangle is a 2-dimensional shape.

The sides of most 3-dimensional shapes are themselves 2-dimensional shapes. For example, a tetrahedron has 4 sides, all triangles. Various other shapes also have sides that are triangular, including triangular prisms and triangular pyramids.

> "your task involves arranging the coloured triangles **of** floating three-dimensional geometric figures"

This means that you must arrange the 2-dimensional triangles (which are coloured) that make up 3-dimensional shapes.

To put it another way, it appears that you make 3D shapes out of 2D shapes. Like building a piece of flat-pack furniture - you start out with flat pieces, but in the end you have something 3-dimensional.